# Select last 30 items per group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery, limit

Hopefully the title makes any sense.

For this example I'll have the next table in my database

```
measurements
==================================
stn | date        | temp | time  =
1   | 01-12-2001  | 2.0  | 14:30 =
1   | 01-12-2001  | 2.1  | 14:31 =
1   | 03-12-2001  | 1.9  | 21:34 =
2   | 01-12-2001  | 4.5  | 12:48 =
2   | 01-12-2001  | 4.7  | 12:49 =
2   | 03-12-2001  | 4.9  | 11:01 =
==================================
```

And so on and so forth.

Each station (stn) has many measurements, one per <strike>day</strike> **second**. Now I want to select the temp of each station of the last 30 <strike>days</strike> **measurements** where the station has at least 30 temperature measurements.

I was playing with subquerys and group by, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Hope someone can help me out here.

**edited the table**
My example was oversimplified leaving a critical piece of information out. Please review the question.

Comment: 30 *consecutive* days or simply 30 days?

Comment: The last 30 measurements indeed. (Not days, please review the question)

Answer (score 2):

```
select t1.stn,t1.date,t1.temp,t1.rn from (
select *,
   @num := if(@stn = stn, @num + 1, 1) as rn,
   @stn := stn as id_stn
from table,(select @stn := 0, @num := 1) as r
order by stn asc, date desc) as t1
inner join (select `stn`
           from table
          where concat_ws(' ',date,time) >= now() - interval 30 day
          group by `stn`
         having count(*) >= 30) as t
on t1.stn = t.stn
and t1.rn <= 30
order by stn,date desc,time desc
```

Comment: Okay, my example table was wrong I see now. There is not only a date field but also a time field. Which means there are multiple measurements on a day. I over simplified the example leaving this critical piece of information out in the way. It however is still the last 30 measurement points per station which I would like to fetch from the table. --- Working with an interval of 30 days is not an option this way. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: Wow, I seriously don't have the slightest idea how this query would work. There's got to be an easier way. I quess my question is phrased wrong.

Answer (score 2):

This is the query that should select `Last 30 entries where there are at least 30 entries for a station`

This query is based on the answer here by `nick rulez`, so please upvote him

```
SELECT t1.stn, t1.date, t1.temp, t1.time FROM 
    (
        SELECT *,
            @num := if(@stn = stn, @num + 1, 1) as rn,
            @stn := stn as id_stn
        FROM 
            `tablename`, 
            (SELECT @stn := 0, @num := 1) as r
        ORDER BY stn asc, date desc
    ) as t1
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT `stn`
        FROM `tablename` 
        GROUP BY `stn`
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 30
    ) as t
ON t1.stn = t.stn
AND t1.rn <= 30
ORDER BY stn, date desc, time desc
```

I have tested it on a sample database I made based on your schema and is working fine.

To know more about such queries have a look here [Within-group quotas (Top N per group)](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#104)

Comment: The 'at least 30 days' is 'at least 30 values'. Sorry if that was not clear after my edit.

Comment: @Matthijn I have updated the query and it should now work as per your requirement

Comment: It seems to be the correct query however it is WAY too slow. Think i'll have to rethink how I am going to do this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT stn, date, temp FROM
(
SELECT stn, date, temp, @a:=IF(@lastStn=stn, @a+1, 1) countPerStn, @lastStn:=stn 
FROM cache 
GROUP BY stn, date
ORDER BY stn, date DESC
) as tempTable 
WHERE countPerStn > 30;
```

Is the query I was looking for, sorry if my question was 'so wrong' that it pushed you all in the wrong direction. I'll up vote the answers who'm helped me to find the needed query.